# React (Gatsby) deactivate Google Analytics in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, analytics, gatsby

How to create a deactive Goole Analytics link in Gatsby.JS? My link doesn't deactivate Google Analytics.

Used plugins:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-tracking/?=gd

I have a link that should deactivate Google Analytics:

```
  <Link
      href="javascript:gaOptout();"
      data-ua={process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID}
    >
      Deactivate Google Analytics
    </Link>
```

But I always get the following error message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: gaOptout is not defined at :1:1

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that function yourself it is not included in GA.

You can find an example of such funciton in in the documentation of `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`:

> **anonymize**
>   Some countries (such as Germany) require you to use the _anonymizeIP function for Google Analytics. Otherwise you are not allowed to use it. The option adds two blocks to the code:
>
> ```
> function gaOptout(){document.cookie=disableStr+'=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC;path=/',window[disableStr]=!0}var gaProperty='UA-XXXXXXXX-X',disableStr='ga-disable-'+gaProperty;document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr+'=true')>-1&&(window[disableStr]=!0);
>
> ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', 1);
> ```
>
> If your visitors should be able to set an Opt-Out-Cookie (No future tracking) you can set a link e.g. in your imprint as follows:
>
> ```
> <a href="javascript:gaOptout();">Deactivate Google Analytics</a>
> ```
>
> https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics/

Comment: I know this example. But how can I use this in my react code?  I can't just call a ga function.

Comment: Check if you have 'gtag' function AFAIK `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` is using Google Tag Manager to push events to Google Analytics, maybe your solution is using it too.

Comment: Also maybe you are calling ga before this library is available and you have to add some logic to append that action when the library is available.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up Google Analytics with the [gatsby-pluging-google-gtag](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/)  plugin with programmatic opt-out like so:

### 1. Install the plugin

```
npm install gatsby-plugin-google-gtag
```

### 2. Add plugin to your `gatsby-config.js`

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        // You can add multiple tracking ids and a pageview event will be fired for all of them.
        trackingIds: [
          "UA-XXXXXXXXX-X", // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
        // puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
        head: true,
        // enable ip anonymization (relevant for GDPR)
        anonymize: true,
      },
    },
```

### 3. Add button in privacy page to allow a user to opt out of Google Analytics

To programmatically opt out a person from Google Analytics, you need to set an opt out cookie in the `onClick` handler of your button.

```
<button onClick={() => {
    // TODO: replace UA-XXXXXXXXX-X with your tracking id. Make sure to not delete any other characters
    document.cookie = "ga-disable-UA-XXXXXXXXX-X=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC;path=/";
    window.disableStr = 1;
    alert("opt out successful");
}}>
```

The `onClick` handler basically does pretty much the same as [Gatsby suggests in their documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/#the-gtagconfiganonymize_ip-option)

Please note that you need to replace the `UA-XXXXXXXXX-X` with the proper tracking id from your Google Analytics admin panel. You might also consider using an env var for the tracking id to keep the code base `DRY`.

### Caveats

The plugin does not load Google Analytics when you run:

```
gatsby develop
```

You need to run

```
gatsby build && gatsby serve
```

**Please also make sure that your browser does not block the analytics script from the start (e.g. Brave browser)**. Otherwise, it won't work. After you have clicked the button you should see an additional cookie in the developer console.